# Is it okay to build Mac App Store apps for 64 bit arch only?

Tags: cocoa, macos, 64-bit, mac-app-store

I wonder if I should still support 32-bit architectures these days in my new apps. I only target Mac App Store.

Does Snow Leopard ever run 32-bit variants? (I guess yes, on older Core Duo CPUs that don't support 64 bit mode?)

Does Lion ever run 32-bit variants? (I guess no?)

The reason it's tempting to give up 32-bit arch is to use the new Objective-C runtime (which, for example, allows synthesized ivars).

UPDATE: published 64-bit only version. So far no reports about not being able to install it.

Comment: Are you sure the new runtime is just for Lion only and being 64-bit-only is a coincidence?

Comment: @Steve-o: I don't think he was saying the new runtime is for Lion only. He wants to abandon 32-bit because the new runtime is 64-bit-only.

Comment: @Peter but the runtime wouldn't be backward compatible either, you would have to build for Snow Leopard and use forward compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point I would say it's alright. Mac OS X Lion can only be installed on 64-bit compatable computers.

Anything above an Intel Core Solo or Duo ( Core Solo and Core Duo are 32-bit Intel processors), is 64-bit compatable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll publish a 64-bit only beta build and see.

Answer (score 0):

If you look the iLife-suite provided by Apple for example, these software are still running 32-bits. So this architecture is far from being dead.

Comment: Newer versions of Apple software like Keynote 6.1 are 64-bit only.